# Is the MSTestExtensions project compatible with VS2010?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, mstest, integration-testing

We've been using VS2008 and soon will be upgrading to VS2010. I have been using [MSTestExtensions](http://mstestextensions.codeplex.com/) for it's database rollback feature for integration tests via MSTest. It seems the open source project has not been having much contribution in the last 2-3 years. Thus, I was curious if anyone has tried to use it with VS2010. Does it still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can now verify that **the 2008 MSTestExtensions dll does indeed work with Visual Studio 2010**.

The only thing is it didn't show up in the list of .net references so I had to manually browse to where it was installed. In my case that was to C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MSTestExtensions. Just add a reference to the version 2.0 dll (VS 2008 version) and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that you can download the source code to the MSTestExtensions project, it might be worth getting the source and building it in VS 2010. Since the MSTest functionality in VS 2010 has not changed that much since VS 2008 (from what I've read), I would say you have a good possibility of getting the code to build. The resulting binaries could be used for your VS 2010 development (hopefully! :)

Comment: This is a good idea, and I would have gone this route if using the 2008 extension would not have worked. +1 for the suggestion.